# How to update a current page without refreshing it using node?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, websocket, socket.io, mean-stack

Im trying to create a web page similar to Facebook Home page using MEAN stack. 
So when you add a new post, the page adds the post  without refreshing it. And if I delete the post the page will delete the post without refreshing the page also.

Should I be using Ajax, Socket io, or etc? not really sure what is the best practice to implement that.

if you have a working example, that will be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What are you asking for is a situation called server-push where you want the server to be able to notify an open web page about some sort of change so Javascript in the page can then update the display of the page without reloading it.

The usual way in modern browsers to implement server-push is to make a webSocket connection from the browser web page back to the server.  This webSocket connection will then stay open and the server is free to send messages to the web page at any time (announcing new posts or deleted posts) and the Javascript in the webpage can then update the display accordingly.

A common implementation of webSocket that works in node.js and all browsers is the socket.io library that you mentioned.  It adds some useful features on top of webSockets such as auto-reconnect and a simple message-passing system.

The other less-efficient way to do this is for each web page to send a recurring ajax call (say every minute) to the server asking what has changed recently.  But, since this results in a lot of ajax calls where nothing has changed, this can end up being significantly less efficient for both server load and bandwidth usage.

Answer (score 0):

SocketStream is a good solution:
https://github.com/socketstream/socketstream

There are many examples.  It will take some time.